# Changing swappiness in sysctl.conf doesn't work for me

Tags: swap, system-settings

I'm using 12.04 LTS and can sudo sysctl to set swappiness to 10, but adding vm.swappiness=10 to sysctl.conf doesn't work for me - after I reboot, swappiness still reports 60 (default)

I'd like to be able to reduce swaps to my SSD, but can't find a way to do so except manually per session. Modifying sysctl.conf seems to work for most - can anyone advise what I need to check / change to make it work for me too, please?

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do is  create a custom rule in `/etc/sysctl.d/` instead of editing the main `sysctl` file. Change directory to `sysctl.d` and create your file:

```
cd /etc/sysctl.d/ 
sudo touch 60-my-swappiness.conf
```

Then run your favourite text editor:

```
sudo nano 60-my-swappiness.conf
```

Enter your value at the top of the file, for example, `vm.swappiness = 10` (there must be **spaces** between swappiness and the value as shown).

As it recommends in the *readme* in `/etc/sysctl.d/`, run

```
sudo service procps start
```

for the system to read the new values and then reboot.

The reason why we use `60` at the start of the `my-swappiness.conf` is so that your custom rule overrides any other rules in the directory.

Check that you have the correct swappiness with

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
10
```

This works for me, but there is more guidance on swap and swappiness in the [Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) if you need any more detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

1. See what the current value is for the swappiness setting:

   `sudo cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`
   (It should give a number of 60 here)
2. Change the value to a lower number

   `sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=5`
3. Check the value again.

   `sudo cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`
   (Now, it should give a value of 5 here)
4. `gksu gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`

   Paste the following line on the text file that opened:

   `vm.swappiness = 5`

(You have `vm.swappiness=10` when it should read `vm.swappiness = 10`)

1. Reboot.
2. Check the setting again to confirm the changes were made:

   `sudo cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`
   (Now, it should give a number 5 here)