# Setting swappiness in /etc/sysctl.conf and /etc/sysctl.d/ doesn't persist after reboot

Tags: swap, 19.10

This has been asked a [number](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269919/swappiness-setting-ignored-in-sysctl-conf) [of](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192304/changing-swappiness-in-sysctl-conf-doesnt-work-for-me) [times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443032/etc-sysctl-conf-doesnt-persist-after-reboot) [before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053997/etc-sysctl-conf-settings-do-not-last-after-reboot). However, at the risk of being flagged a duplicate I thought I would ask again, as I have not seen answers specific to Ubuntu 19.10, and none of these recommended answers works for me.

**In short:**
Setting `vm.swappiness = 10` directly in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, or creating a file `/etc/sysctl.d/60-my-swappiness.conf` with the content `vm.swappiness = 10`, does not change the swappiness on boot; it remains at the default value of 60:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
```

Running `sysctl -p` with `sudo` permissions changes it for the given session, but on reboot it resets back to the default.

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
[sudo] password for user: 
vm.swappiness = 10
...
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
10
```

**How do you change the swappiness so that it persists between reboots in Ubuntu 19.10?**

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you make a [sysctl.d(5)](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/sysctl.d.5) [configuration file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/sysctl.d.5.html) so the configuration is set at boot time, with contents similar to:

```
/etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf
vm.swappiness=10
```

Comment: I have already done this with no success. Does it matter what the file is called? I chose `/etc/sysctl.d/60-my-swappiness.conf` but I was under the impression it was irrelevant

Comment: also, I believe the line must have spaces between the variable and the value (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269919/swappiness-setting-ignored-in-sysctl-conf))

Comment: Yes, the name is important.

Comment: doesn't work for me I'm afraid

Comment: Drat. Anyone else?